# MVC, Putting lineBreak inside <fieldset><p> when encountering this character

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

In our database, the admin decided that `{` represent a linebreak.

Seems simple.

Now MVC, I have the field inside this :

```
<fieldset class="my-fieldset">
    <legend>Whatever</legend>
    <p> @StringVariable.Replace("{", "???") </p> 
</fieldset>
```

I don't know what to put here `???`

These were my trys :

```
<p> @StringVariable.Replace("{", "<p></p>") </p> 
<p> @StringVariable.Replace("{", "<br/>") </p> 
<p> @StringVariable.Replace("{", "\r\n") </p> 
<p> @StringVariable.Replace("{", "&#10") </p>
```

It dosen't linebreak...

Maybe i should put something after the @ that would make things work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first we need to be clear about what you mean by "linebreak". Are you wanting a line break in the HTML source or a line break in the rendered document? When HTML is parsed, whitespace is ignored unless contained within a `pre` tag or otherwise styled as "preformatted text". So, adding a line break in the source within something like a `<p>` tag, will just be ignored in the browser's rendering, regardless. The only thing that will cause an actual *rendered* line break is the `<br />` tag. So, most likely, what you're looking for is:

```
<p>@StringVariable.Replace("{", "<br />")</p>
```

However, Razor automatically HTML encodes string data for safety. If you want to actually have HTML within a string treated as HTML, you need to wrap it with `Html.Raw`:

```
 <p>@Html.Raw(StringVariable.Replace("{", "<br />"))</p>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the kind of answer that explains EVERYTHING, Many thanks

Comment: When `StringVariable` ultimately comes from the user or a third party, this can result in code injection. Explicitely use `Html.Encode` before doing the string replace to prevent code injection.

Comment: Thanks, i'll remember that @NineBerry

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I have updated my answer to show how you can write a html helper extension in case you need this at multiple places.

Answer (score 2):

First encode the string using `Html.Encode()` to escape potential html syntax. Then replace the placeholder with the `<br/>` tag. Then output the string using `Html.Raw()`, so that no more html escaping is applied:

```
<fieldset class="my-fieldset">
     <legend>Whatever</legend>
     <p> @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(StringVariable).Replace("{", "<br/>")) </p> 
</fieldset>
```

---

If you need this at several places, write your own HTML helper extension method like this:

```
public static class HTMLExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ApplyNewLineReplacing(this HtmlHelper html, string text)
    {
        text = html.Encode(text);
        text = text.Replace("{", "<br/>");

        return html.Raw(text);
    }
}
```

You can then use this in your view like this:

```
<fieldset class="my-fieldset">
     <legend>Whatever</legend>
     <p> @Html.ApplyNewLineReplacing(StringVariable) </p> 
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
<p>@StringVariable.Replace("{", System.Environment.NewLine)</p>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm going to split the string and put that in a damn foreach... so tired of this <p> really...